# Error after scanning ISBN code

Tags: swift, xcode

I have a view controller in my application that scans ISBN codes and this is the class:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class QRScannerController: UIViewController, AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var messageLabel: UILabel!

static var isbn : String = ""

var captureSession:AVCaptureSession?
var videoPreviewLayer:AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?
var qrCodeFrameView:UIView?

let supportedCodeTypes = [AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN13Code]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Get an instance of the AVCaptureDevice class to initialize a device object and provide the video as the media type parameter.
    let captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)

    do {
        // Get an instance of the AVCaptureDeviceInput class using the previous device object.
        let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice)

        // Initialize the captureSession object.
        captureSession = AVCaptureSession()

        // Set the input device on the capture session.
        captureSession?.addInput(input)

        // Initialize a AVCaptureMetadataOutput object and set it as the output device to the capture session.
        let captureMetadataOutput = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()
        captureSession?.addOutput(captureMetadataOutput)

        // Set delegate and use the default dispatch queue to execute the call back
        captureMetadataOutput.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)
        captureMetadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes = supportedCodeTypes

        // Initialize the video preview layer and add it as a sublayer to the viewPreview view's layer.
        videoPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
        videoPreviewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
        videoPreviewLayer?.frame = view.layer.bounds
        view.layer.addSublayer(videoPreviewLayer!)

        // Start video capture.
        captureSession?.startRunning()

        // Move the message label and top bar to the front
        view.bringSubview(toFront: messageLabel)
        //view.bringSubview(toFront: topbar)

        // Initialize QR Code Frame to highlight the QR code
        qrCodeFrameView = UIView()

        if let qrCodeFrameView = qrCodeFrameView {
            qrCodeFrameView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
            qrCodeFrameView.layer.borderWidth = 2
            view.addSubview(qrCodeFrameView)
            view.bringSubview(toFront: qrCodeFrameView)
        }

    } catch {
        // If any error occurs, simply print it out and don't continue any more.
        print(error)
        return
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


// MARK: - AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate Methods

func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputMetadataObjects metadataObjects: [Any]!, from connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {

    // Check if the metadataObjects array is not nil and it contains at least one object.
    if metadataObjects == nil || metadataObjects.count == 0 {
        qrCodeFrameView?.frame = CGRect.zero
        messageLabel.text = "No QR/barcode is detected"
        return
    }

    // Get the metadata object.
    let metadataObj = metadataObjects[0] as! AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject

    if supportedCodeTypes.contains(metadataObj.type) {
        // If the found metadata is equal to the QR code metadata then update the status label's text and set the bounds
        let barCodeObject = videoPreviewLayer?.transformedMetadataObject(for: metadataObj)
        qrCodeFrameView?.frame = barCodeObject!.bounds

        if metadataObj.stringValue != nil {
            messageLabel.text = metadataObj.stringValue
            QRScannerController.isbn = metadataObj.stringValue
            print(QRScannerController.isbn)
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showISBN", sender: self)
        }
    }
}
```

}

It scans the exact code and I save it in the var isbn. The error is when I perform the segue because it returns to previous view controller more than one time and I want only one. I tried to print the variable `isbn` and it is printed many times, like this: "
9788804648666
9788804648666
9788804648666
9788804648666
9788804648666
9788804648666
9788804648666
9788804648666
9788804648666
9788804648666
9788804648666
9788804648666
9788804648666
9788804648666
9788804648666
9788804648666
9788804648666
9788804648666
9788804648666
9788804648666
9788804648666
9788804648666
9788804648666"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue comes from the *captureSession* that is still running when you detect à QR code, so your *performSegue* is called many times.
Instead, you should replace

```
if metadataObj.stringValue != nil {
  messageLabel.text = metadataObj.stringValue
  QRScannerController.isbn = metadataObj.stringValue
  print(QRScannerController.isbn)
  self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showISBN", sender: self)
}
```

By

```
if let code = metadataObj.stringValue {
  saveAndDismiss(code: code)
}
```

And add

```
fileprivate func saveAndDismiss(code code: String) {
  messageLabel.text = code
  QRScannerController.isbn = code
  print(QRScannerController.isbn)
  performSegue(withIdentifier: "showISBN", sender: self)
  captureSession?.stopRunning()
}
```

Moreover, your isbn var shouldn't be static. It should be private, and you can give the value to the segue destination controller in the méthode *prepareForSegue*

Answer (score 0):

I would even replace the whole func like that :

```
func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputMetadataObjects metadataObjects: [Any]!, from connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {
  guard let data = metadataObjects,
  data.count > 0 else {
    qrCodeFrameView?.frame = CGRect.zero
    messageLabel.text = "No QR/barcode is detected"
    return
  }

  // Get the metadata object.
  if let metadataObj = metadataObjects[0] as? AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject,
  supportedCodeTypes.contains(metadataObj.type) {
    // If the found metadata is equal to the QR code metadata then update the status label's text and set the bounds
    if let barCodeObject = videoPreviewLayer?.transformedMetadataObject(for: metadataObj) {
     qrCodeFrameView?.frame = barCodeObject.bounds
    }

    if let code = metadataObj.stringValue {
      saveAndDismiss(code: code)
    }
  }
}
```